# Is it possible to override Tomcat HTTP connector properties in server.xml via JAVA_OPTS?

Tags: java, tomcat, docker

I'm interested to know if you can override HTTP connector [properties](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html) like `port`, `protocol`, `scheme` etc. typically set in the `server.xml` file by passing in Catalina environment variables to the JVM at runtime?

This is so that I can pass in environment variables to a tomcat Docker application container without having to touch the default `server.xml` file.

For example is it enough to set the `-DcatalinaConnectorProxyName` in the `JAVA_OPTS` environment variable at JVM runtime to override the default setting in the `server.xml` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15555838/how-to-pass-tomcat-port-number-on-command-line

Comment: Does it fulfill your requirement?

Comment: Hi @TonyY, yes that's something I can work with.

Comment: The following also helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045949/change-tomcat-port-on-the-fly